# Python: Forwarding Ctrl-C to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, signals, popen, sigint

I have a Slurm srun wrapper in Python 3.6 that validates command line arguments and then allows the real program to run with those arguments. If the command hangs, I want the Ctrl-C to be passed to the subprocess. I don't care about the program's stdin/out/err; I want the user to interact with it as if there was no python wrapper. This works but is there no way to send signals with subprocess.run()?

```
try:
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/srun'] + argv[1:])
    cmd.wait() 
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cmd.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: Try `cmd.communicate(b"\x03")`

Comment: What does b"\x03" do for communicate()?

Comment: `b"\x03"` or `b"\3"` is a data which you send to *stdin* of opened process. It's "[End Of Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Text_character)" char. If `b"\3"` not working, try to add newline `b"\3\n"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with run() but Popen does the trick. With this change I can get all the output from srun (even after the Ctrl-C), as well as capture the exit value of srun.

```
try:
    with subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/srun'] + argv[1:]) as cmd:
        cmd.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cmd.send_signal(SIGINT)
exit(cmd.returncode)
```

Comment: Where SIGINT is defined in the signal module (which needs to be imported)

Comment: And the `cmd` variable is still valid after the `with` block has completed?  It looks it is, but I was expecting it to be "closed" after the `with` block exited.